# Check if List<dynamic> contains an integer

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm still new to DART but I thought this would be easy to accomplish.

I want to check if a List from a future contains an integer. My return type is list dynamic but when I do the check it's telling me it's a Future.

The function that returns a List dynamic

I want to change the color of an icon

```
Icon(
      Icons.favorite,
      color: checkIfLiked(), // Change color here using a future.
      size: buttonSize,
                  );



Future<List> userLikes() async {
        GetUserLikes userLikesClicks = GetUserLikes();
        Future<List> userLikes = userLikesClicks.getLikes();
        List userList = await userLikes;
        return userList; // returns List<dynamic>
      }
```

I want to check of the Array contains an integer and if it does to return a color.

```
Future<Color> checkIfLiked() async{
Color color;
List resultUsersLikes = await userLikes();

if (resultUsersLikes.contains(widget.id)) {
  color = Colors.blue;
} else {
  color = Colors.grey;
}
return color;
```

}

I have to return a Color, and I am already using a FutureBuilder on the widget.

I need the color to change the color of an icon.

This is the icon

```
Icon(
    Icons.favorite,
    color: checkIfLiked(),
    size: buttonSize,
     );
```

How can I add an async here to await the future?

Comment: Using dynamic is consider poor form unless you truly don't know the type. Add a type to your list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I see the `userLikes()` is a `Future` method, which means when you do this:

```
   if (userLikes().contains(widget.id)) {
   // ....
```

you're trying to call `contains()` which belongs to the `List` type on a `Future` which didn't resolve yet to return the `userList` from it.

what you need to do is to wait until it gets it and resolves, then use its result ( which will be a `List` ), like this:

```
    Future<Color> checkIfLiked() async { // add async
    List resultUsersLikes = await userLikes(); // then await for this
    Color color;
    if (resultUsersLikes.contains(widget.id)) { // then use it here 
      color = Colors.blue;
    } else {
      color = Colors.grey;
    }
    return color;
  }
```

Now when you call `checkIfLiked()`, first it will get the response from the `userLikes()` then store it in `resultUsersLikes`, then use it in the rest of your code :

and when you wanna use `checkIfLiked()` in your other codes as the `onPressed` of some button, you will need to `await` for it to get its final response, like this:

```
onPressed: () async {
  Color colorResult = await checkIfLiked();
}
```

You can set that color to the `Icon`, by calling this method on `initState`, then once it completes, update the state with the `Color`, first declare a `Color` variable in your `State` class:

```
Color? resultColor;
```

then set it to your `Icon`:

```
Icon(
    Icons.favorite,
    color: resultColor,
    size: buttonSize,
   );
```

then in your `initState`:

```
@override
void initState() {
 checkIfLiked().then((colorResponse) {
  setState(() {
    resultColor = colorResponse
  });
 });
}
```

now once the widget will be set inside the widget tree, the `checkIfLiked()` will get called, when it finishes, the `then` will be executed, which updates the state of `resultColor` with the color got from the method.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I had done something similar but this has to change the color of an Icon when it loads via a listBuilder.

Is there away of changing it by onload instead of onTap?

I have updated the question.

Comment: I will edit the post for a solution that will fit

Comment: Thanks, for your help, I was able to work it out there from, an issue I had was I needed two Furture Builders and to use future.wait()

Answer (score 0):

Like your error message states, The method 'contains' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. You should first await the future to resolve, and then you can use the List it returns. First of all, your checkIfLiked() function must return Future and inside it you should await userLikes() function.

```
Future<Color> checkIfLiked() async {
    Color color;
    if ((await userLikes()).contains(widget.id)) {
      color = Colors.blue;
    } else {
      color = Colors.grey;
    }
    return color;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want `checkIfLiked()` to return a `Future<Color>`, you can try this

First declare a variable color and give it a default value.

```
  Color color = Colors.grey;
```

Then call the below method `checkIfLiked()` when you need to.
It will fetch the list of likes and finds the required color based on your logic.

Then it uses `setState` to change the variable color's value from default value grey to required value.

Color change will happen automatically in all your widgets, where `color` is referenced.

```
  Future<void> checkIfLiked() async {
    List userLikesList = await userLikes();
    setState(() {
      if (userLikesList.contains(widget.id)) {
        color = Colors.blue;
      } else {
        color = Colors.grey;
      }
    });
  }
```